# Ansible correct way to get a virtualenv with a recent version of setuptools and pip

Tags: pip, virtualenv, ansible

Hello today to get a virtualenv runing with vagrant (1.7.4)

I first install `python-virtualenv` with apt::

```
- name: Apt install
  apt: name={{ item }} state=installed update_cache=yes
  with_items:
    ## needed to make virtualenv
    - python-dev
    - python-setuptools
    - python-virtualenv
```

The with eassy_install I get pip::

```
- easy_install: name=pip
```

I create virtualenv with `shell:`:

```
- name: == Create virtualenv
  shell: virtualenv "{{ venv_name }}"
  args:
    chdir: "{{ home }}"
  sudo: true
  sudo_user: "{{ user }}"

- name: Upgrade pip wheel and setuptools
  pip: name={{ item }} virtualenv="{{ home }}/{{ venv_name }}"
       extra_args='--upgrade'
  with_items:
    - pip
    - wheel
    - setuptools
```

And End with pip giving the virtualenv info::

```
- name: pip Install packages into virtualenv
  pip: >
    name={{ item }} virtualenv="{{ home }}/{{ venv_name }}"
    virtualenv_site_packages="no"
  with_items:
    - ansicolors
    - blist
```

Is that the correct way to get a virtualenv with a recent version of setuptools and pip ?:

```
(venv)toto@vagrant-ubuntu-wily-64:~$ python -c "import pkg_resources as pkg; print(pkg.require(['setuptools'])[0].version)"
20.10.1
(venv)toto@vagrant-ubuntu-wily-64:~$ pip -V
pip 8.1.1 from /home/toto/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (python 2.7)
(venv)toto@vagrant-ubuntu-wily-64:~$ wheel version
wheel 0.29.0
(venv)toto@vagrant-ubuntu-wily-64:~$
```

Answer (score 1):

You can require the latest version:

```
- name: Upgrade pip wheel and setuptools
  pip: name={{ item }} virtualenv="{{ home }}/{{ venv_name }}" state=latest
       extra_args='--upgrade'
  with_items:
    - pip
    - wheel
    - setuptools

- name: pip Install packages into virtualenv
  pip: >
    name={{ item }} virtualenv="{{ home }}/{{ venv_name }}" state=latest
    virtualenv_site_packages="no"
  with_items:
    - ansicolors
    - blist
```

Comment: Yes this upgrade to the last version if you already have a virutalenv set (it's what I already show in my question). But my question was on the best way (better than using shell) to set up this virtualenv.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this one:

```
- name: install python packages
  pip:
    name: "{{ item.name }}"
    extra_args: "--upgrade"
    virtualenv: "{{ home }}/{{ venv_name }}"
    virtualenv_command: virtualenv
    state: latest
  with_items:
    - pip
    - wheel
    - setuptools
    - ansicolors
    - blist
```

Comment: Yes this upgrade to the last version if you already have a virutalenv set (it's what I already show in my question). But my question was on the best way (better than using shell) to set up this virtualenv.